# configure: error: cannot find D-Bus

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, services, dbus

When configuring a software (subversion) on Ubuntu Linux (10.04 lucid), I get an error:

`configure: error: cannot find D-Bus`

I restarted dbus service:

```
#service dbus restart
dbus start/running, process 14688
```

but still get the same configure error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the daemon, not the dbus development package. You can grab it from spm.

Comment: apt-get says cannot find package dbus-devel.  (I had installed dbus itself using apt-get).

Comment: libdconf-dbus-1-dev is what you're looking for. It has some deps though

Comment: Thanks. That didnt work, but finally, libdbus-1-dev worked for me.

Comment: I though libdconf would grab libdbus as a dep but your right, it doesn't. Seems odd but I guess they had their reasons for doing it like that.